# Implementing download manager

Tags: c#, resume, download-manager

I'm planning on writing a custom download manager as part of an application. To start researching, I'd appreciate pointer/opinions on the following:

- How to detect if the target server supports resume for a given file.
- How to download files in multiple parts.
- Any libraries available for .NET?
- What would be a good the most practical way to go? ThreadPool or TPL?

Comment: Way too many questions at once. And each individual question is way too broad. A true 'answer' to this question would be book-length. (FYI: I did not down vote)

Comment: Why write YADM (yet another download manager)? This has been done several times and [some of them](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx) even include the source.

Comment: @M.Babcock: +1 for the link. To answer your question, my application is commercial so I cannot use any code associated with open source licenses.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: You are probably right. However, the intention was to figure out where to start looking for those four points rather than lengthy answers. I'll add my own answer for the first three. Will launch the fourth question as a separate SO post.

Comment: @RaheelKhan - I understand the license restrictions of commercial applications however at the least if a project is open source you can read their code to figure out *how* they got by your issues (assuming they have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean a HTTP download manager?? For the first 2...
[HTTP Header Field Definitions - Accept-Ranges](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5)